# How to load different configs for bash script from command line arguments?

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to read different configs depending on the argument in the command line.

For example, if the command like this;

```
./app.sh command1
```

then read `. ~/config/config1.conf` file in the system.

if the command is like this;

```
./app.sh command2
```

then read the `. ~/config/config2.conf` file.

So what this will help is that, for example, `config1.conf` has `var=var1` and `config2.conf` has `var=var2` so this will allow me to load different configs with same variable names, but different values.

how can I make such thing?

Comment: Great little project, happy you told us what you are up to.  Do you have a question?  SO is not a code writing service.  But to get you started, read about arguments in bash scripts ($1) and how to do an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `case` statement to select the desired configuration.

```
case $1 in
  command1) cfg=config1 ;;
  command2) cfg=config2 ;;
esac

cfg_file=~/config/"$cfg.conf"
if [ -f "$cfg_file" ]; then
  . "$cfg_file"
fi
```